Controlling MPV via http requests, like VLC, or an alternative
My development tool can't use PIPE/socket connections, so…
Is there another way to control MPV from another application using a different protocol/interface? I need just standard functions: play, pause, get current time, seek, select audio track, etc.
Lua should be an option, but it seems that Lua scripts are executed from inside MPV. I can't find how to execute a Lua script from another application.
I can do that with VLC using its http interface, sending and receiving JSON, but I need another media player.

Is there an another interface, protocol or technique?

Is there another controllable media player for Mac and Windows? (it seems that MPlayer also uses PIPE/Socket for the slave mode, so it's not an option for me).


